# Why cannot escript run?

Tags: erlang, rebar, erlang-escript

rebar is in the current directory.

```
$ls -l rebar
--rwxr-xr-x  1 ***  wheel  90778  8  6 23:05 rebar*
$./rebar
escript: no such file or directory: './rebar'

$whereis escript
escript: /usr/local/bin/escript
```

I am using FreeBSD 9.0.

thanks!

Comment: What does `head -1 ./rebar` say? It seems like your rebar script is looking for escript in the wrong location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change in the beginning of **rebar** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
```

to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env escript
```

or just:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/escript
```